# Update specific state with given key and value?

Tags: reactjs

I want to wrap the `setState` function like something below to save few lines,

```
function updateState(key, value) {
  this.setState({
    key: value 
  })  
}
```

but apparently this is not work, is there a way to wrap this function?

Comment: Have you heard about `recompose` `withState`?

https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstate

Not exactly what you're asking, but might help you on reducing boilerplate.

Comment: no, but I will read more about it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are passing the state in, `this` will reference the function and not your component instance. You are also using the string "key" and not the variable `key`, you probably want [key] instead. You could possibly do the following if you just want a generic setter method.

```
class React extends PureComponent {
  updateState (key, value) {
    return this.setState({
      [key]: value
    })
  }

  ... rest of your component definition
}
```

Hope that helps :)